# Firefox - tabs in drop down list

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

Firefox currently shows a drop-down list of the currently open tabs to the far right of the tab bar.  Is it possible to keep this drop-down list, but hide the rest of the tab bar?  I only want the tabs to be visible in this drop-down menu.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the [Tab Mix Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-mix-plus/) extension. Right-click the menu bar and select **Customize**, drag the tab list button to where you want it (but not on the tab bar!) and close the **Customize** dialog. Go to Tab Mix Plus options and select **Display** (at the top) > **Tab Bar** (tab) > under **Hide the Tab Bar** select **Always**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Vertical Tabs Reloaded](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/vertical-tabs-reloaded/), if you use the Firefox restriquantumted edition.